# how to avoid overflow when converting string to float in java without using java's builtin functions?

Tags: java, string, floating-point

I need to write a method in java that converts a given string to float.
my problem is how to avoid overflows - not to get value bigger than Float.MAX_VALUE AND lower than
Float.MIN_VALUE;

tnx!

Answer (score 1):

Clamp it to the range:

```
float clamped = Math.max(Float.MIN_VALUE, Math.min(Float.MAX_VALUE, Float.parseFloat(yourString)));
```

Note that you say "not ... lower than Float.MIN_VALUE" - this might not be quite what you intend: unlike `Integer` and `Long`'s `MIN_VALUE`, which is large and negative, `Float` and `Double`'s `MIN_VALUE` is a very small positive number.

If you mean that you want `clamped` to be positive, use `max(Float.MIN_VALUE, ...)` as above; if you mean that you don't want it to be negative and infinite, use `max(-Float.MAX_VALUE, ...)` instead.

---

If you need to validate that the value is in the range and throw an exception if not, write a method:

```
float checkRange(float v) {
  if (Float.isNan(v)) throw new IllegalArgumentException("Too not numbery!");
  if (v < Float.MIN_VALUE) throw new IllegalArgumentException("Too small!");
  if (v > Float.MAX_VALUE) throw new IllegalArgumentException("Too big!");
  return v;
}
```

Comment: tnx! can you please provide me an explanation?

Comment: Just think about `min` works if you give it a value less than `Float.MAX_VALUE`, and if you give it a value greater than `Float.MAX_VALUE`. (Same for `max`).

Comment: But it may give wrong value(answer) when overflow occurred.

Comment: so what is the solutin for this? @Md.KawserHabib

Comment: @Md.KawserHabib can you give an example?

Comment: @AndyTurner, when an overflow occurred the above code returns the last boundary Float.MAX_VALUE, that tempered the result, we should throw an exception or we can use BigDecimal

Comment: @Md.KawserHabib OP said not to get a value outside the range, but didn't specify the out-of-range behavior. If `BigDecimal` were to be used, overflow wouldn't be an issue anyway. But sure, you could throw instead of clamping, if that's what is desired.